# How to get the mean of a column without losing decimal places in R using dyplr?

Tags: r

I need to get the mean of the value column but preserve the Lat and Lon decimal places of the following table:

```
value    node_vsn       Lat      Lon
-0.38017      07C   -87.68302 41.91409
-0.03913      08B   -87.59871 41.78861
-0.03724      004   -87.62768 41.87838
-0.17809      072   -87.71299 41.75114
0.76364       06B   -87.66434 41.78676
-0.22900      089   -87.66239 41.89616
-0.59379      08F   -87.66595 41.96162
-2.45677      081   -87.64105 41.82353
-0.68662      086   -87.67917 41.96876
```

I did this:

```
locations <- locations %>%
      group_by(node_vsn, Lat, Lon) %>%
      summarize(mean_size = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I am getting this as a result:

```
node_vsn   Lat   Lon mean_size
   <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
  004      -87.6  41.9   -0.290 
  01C      -87.7  41.8    0.0685
  02A      -87.6  41.7   -0.327 
  06B      -87.7  41.8    0.579 
  072      -87.7  41.8    0.0191
  079      -87.7  41.9   -0.178 
  07C      -87.7  41.9   -0.193 
  081      -87.6  41.8   -2.32
```

The Lat and Lon are losing decimal places and I want to keep them as they are.
options(pillar.sigfig = 7) does not work

Comment: I think it is a `print`formatting by the `tbl_df`.  Please try to extract `locations$Lat` or `locations$Lon` and check if the data changed.  I hope not

Comment: You can check  `locations %>%
  group_by(node_vsn, Lat, Lon) %>%
       summarize(mean_size = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% .$Lat
#[1] -87.62768 -87.66434 -87.71299 -87.68302 -87.64105 -87.66239 -87.59871 -87.66595`

Answer (score 0):

`View(locations)`
To check if the the decimal points have been lost.

You can mutate the Columns to character string.

`locations %>% mutate (Lat = as.character(Lat))`